# how to create a focusable widget

Tags: gwt, uibinder

i have created my own gwt widgets that consist of a TextLabel and an image.
I need that this widget be focusable. I extend this widget from the interface hasFocusHandler, focusable and blurhandler. Nothing is working. I am receiving neither focus nor blur event when i click on or outside of the widget. What should I do?

My code:

```
public class MyWidget extends ComplexPanel implements HasFocusHandlers, HasBlurHandlers, HasClickHandlers, Focusable{

  private Icon icon = new Icon();

  private TextNode text = new TextNode("");

  private static final FocusImpl impl = FocusImpl.getFocusImplForWidget();

  protected static FocusImpl getFocusImpl() {
    return impl;
  }

  public HandlerRegistration addClickHandler(ClickHandler handler) {
    return addDomHandler(handler, ClickEvent.getType());
  }

  @Override
  public HandlerRegistration addBlurHandler(BlurHandler handler) {
    return addDomHandler(handler,BlurEvent.getType());
  }

  @Override
  public HandlerRegistration addFocusHandler(FocusHandler handler) {
    return addDomHandler(handler, FocusEvent.getType());
  } 

  @Override
  public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
    switch (DOM.eventGetType(event)) {
        case Event.ONCLICK:
            if (isEnabled()) {
                super.onBrowserEvent(event);
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onBrowserEvent(event);
            break;
    }
  }

  public int getTabIndex() {
    return impl.getTabIndex(getElement());  
  }

  @Override
  public void setAccessKey(char key) {
    DOM.setElementProperty(getElement(), "accessKey", "" + key);
  }

  @Override
  public void setFocus(boolean focused) {
    if (focused) {
        impl.focus(getElement());
    } else {
        impl.blur(getElement());
    }
  }    

  @Override
  public void setTabIndex(int index) {
    impl.setTabIndex(getElement(), index);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onAttach() {
    super.onAttach();

    int tabIndex = getTabIndex();
    if (-1 == tabIndex) {
        setTabIndex(0);
    }
  }
}
```

My implementation is not working  (I am not receiving the onFocus call, when i click on the myWidget)

```
mywidget.addFocusHandler(new FocusHandler()
{
    @Override
    public void onFocus(FocusEvent event) {
    //DO SOMETHING                  
    }               
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should have more information, because I miss some code, for example, where do you attach the Icon and TextNode to the DOM?

I have done one example and it works for me. Look:

```
@UiField Label labelText;

public MyWidget(String text) {
  super();
  //That is the key. Attach the widgets to the dom
  setElement(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this).getElement()); 
  labelText.setText(text);
}
```

Also instead of having my internal widgets declared in the class, I have created a UiBinder class. Basically:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM 'http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent'>
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder' 
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
  <ui:style>
  </ui:style>

  <g:FlowPanel>
    <g:Label ui:field="labelText">
    </g:Label>      
  </g:FlowPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

In that case you can attach your widgets to the Panel quicker and easier. and in the constructor do only a setElement().

If you have any doubt, just ask!